# Derivation of the Angular Component of Spherical Harmonics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, spherical-harmonics

Every derivation of spherical harmonics seems to tell me that $e^{im\phi}$ is the most obvious solution in the world to $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \phi^2} = -m^2f$. But what about $Ae^{im\phi} + Be^{-im\phi}$ ?  Isn't that a more general, more "correct" solution?  Whether it's spherical harmonics or particle on a ring, I always run into $e^{im\phi}$ and  $e^{-im\phi}$ as separate solutions.  But why, when the general form involves writing them as a linear combination?

I think at the heart of it is their orthogonality, and in physics the subspace formed by the degeneracy of $m$ and $-m$, as well as the connection to the angular momentum operator $L_z$.  But I can't really unpack it into a strictly mathematical explanation for why in none of the derivations they are ever presented initially as a linear combination.  I feel like the derivation should at least begin there, before separating the two terms into distinct solutions.  Or am I missing something, and is there a good reason why they are treated as separate from the start?

Comment: Of course your hunch is correct. The solutions form a two-dimensional vector space, spanned (over $\Bbb C$) by $e^{im\phi}$ and $e^{-im\phi}$ or (over $\Bbb R$) by $\cos m\phi$ and $\sin m\phi$. In each case, we get one eigenvector for $d/d\phi$ (working over $\Bbb C$ you want $i\,d/d\phi$ or $-i\,d/d\phi$) with eigenvalue $m>0$ and one with eigenvalue $m<0$.

Comment: But why do the derivations never bother with the general form that uses linear combinations of the two exponentials?  From what I've seen they just treat the solutions separately.

Comment: They should not. In general, we tend to give a basis for the space of solutions and remind folks that you need as many constants (initial conditions) as the order of the differential equation.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the "extra seasoning" that you need is that the solutions must be periodic:

$$f(\phi) = f(2 \pi m + \phi).$$

This is what forces $m$ to be an integer, and then leads to the general solution

$$f(\phi) = Ae^{im \phi} + Be^{-im \phi}.$$

Comment: I understand that m must be an integer.  My confusion is that despite imposing the periodic constraint, Wikipedia and every other derivation I've seen of spherical harmonics online states that the solution is just a single exponential, and it separates the cases of positive and negative m.

For example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_ring

Why is it in the section on energy eigenvalues, they impose the boundary condition separately for the two exponentials, rather than on the general solution you wrote?  Derivations I've seen dealing with harmonics never deal with the general form.

Comment: Check out Ted's comment to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct. And this is a good question.

The general solution *is* $A_m e^{im\phi}+B_me^{-im\phi}$ where $m\in\mathbb{Z}$. (Note that there is some amount of redundancy in this notation since just the meanings of $A_m$ and $B_m$ are interchanged for $m<0$ compared to $m>0$.) As usual, we require some sort of boundary condition to select the desired constants $A_m, B_m$.

So consider general solutions of the form $\tilde{Y}_{\ell}^m = N_{\ell m} P_\ell^m [A_m e^{im\phi}+B_me^{-im\phi}]$, where $N_{\ell m}$ is some normalization and $P_\ell^m$ are the associated Legendre functions.

Now, we know that $-\ell \le m \le \ell$ and that there exists an operator $L_+$, which when acting on $\tilde Y_\ell^\ell$ gives zero. ($L_+$ is the 'raising operator.' I'm not quoting sources or formulas here since the material is standard.) When you work-out the details, using the form of $L_+$ you'll find that you cannot construct eigenfunctions of $L^2$ and $L_z$ (say) for functions which have both $A_m$ and $B_m$ non-zero.